# jquery mobile popup doesn't show up.

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I have a problem with my jquery mobile popup. It shows only the data-overlay. The popup will be shown after a click in the contextmenu.

I'm making a redirect to a site, then I will open the popup.

```
$.mobile.changePage("#account"); //redirect
setTimeout(function(){
   $('#popupCloseRight').popup("open"); // open the popup but shows only
},100);                                    the grey overlay
```

HTML code:

```
<div data-role="popup" data-overlay-theme="a" id="popupCloseRight" class="ui-content" style="max-width:280px">
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
    <p>Check your E-mail</p>
</div>
```

Comment: JSfiddle will be great

Comment: why are u opening a popup after redirecting? where does this popup lie? is it inside `#account` page? Only then will it open.

Comment: After a registration, it will redirect to the account page. There should be shown the popup, that he should check his email and yes it is inside the '#account' page. It shows the grey background but not the popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is a **jquery mobile bug** , When im changing the size of the browser the popup will be shown.. but thanks.